# Name of the node and search box cartodb

Tags: carto

I'm using cartodb for a project. I read the documentation yet I can't find a solution. 
Indeed, I need to be able to see the name of a node (which is on the name field of the bdd) without clicking on. Is that possible ?

And I have another question. In the search box, is that possible to look for one of our node ?

Thanks a lot

Sincerely
A.H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can label your features on your maps using either the CartoDB wizards or by adding a simple set of CartoCSS rules to your visualization like the ones below:

```
#your_table_name::labels {
  text-name: [your_column_name];
  text-placement: point;
  text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
  text-size: 11;
  text-fill: #000;
  text-halo-fill: #FFF;
  text-halo-radius: 1;
  text-dy: -10;
  text-allow-overlap: true;
  text-placement-type: dummy;
  text-label-position-tolerance: 0;
}
```

About the search box, is a feature that is proposed but it's not implemented yet. By implementing your map with CartoDB.js you could do a workaround quite easy by querying the BBDD to get the lat/lon of your feature and then moving the map to those coordinates.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try soon. For the search box, it's not so much important so I will see what I could do (I'm not really a power user of js currently) but I will try.

Thanks
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

To add to saleiva's response, yes with CartoDB.js it seems like nothing is impossible. To get you started, I know of one good example that uses a column of names to populate an autofill search, http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/7932459

When you select your name, you could also parse the lat/lng of the data.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see what I can do with that :-)
Have a nice day